# How to design Invoices group on this schema

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am working on a School Management System. As you can see a student can be registered to multiple Organization. All registrations can be invoiced.

For instance last month Registration 1 has been invoiced for a total of 1000$ and the Parents receive the invoice of their child.

**The problem**

So : 1 invoice = 1 registration

Now, what if parents want only ONE invoice per month for all their children (1 invoices for 4 registrations) ? (this should be optional just for some parents, not all)

**Possible Solution**

My idea, as invoice relations are already polymorphic, what if instead of Registration, Parent 1 is billed directly?

What do you think?

PS: please note that every invoices have a reference like: INV-000XXX and should be unique

[image: database schema]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your scenario by adding another table "Invoice Line Item"

### Invoices

- id
- invoice_no (reference) unique
- parent_id

### Invoice_line_item

- id
- invoice_id (Foreign Key of Invoice)
- registration_id (FK of Registration) (One -> Many relationship)

Now you can create invoice whether there is a single child or multiple children of a parent.

I believe you understood this relation. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: invoice_line already exists and I'm afraid that's an anti pattern :/